# Implementing pagination in wp doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add some code to my wordpress theme to show a pagination at the bottom of the posts.
Here's my loop with the pagination:

```
<main id="main">

            <?php 
            // the query
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 2 );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

            ?>

            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

                <!-- loop -->

                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
       <article id="post"> 

                    <div id="thumbnail">

                        <?php
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                             the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

                </div>

               <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

               <div class="entry">

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

               </div>


       </article>


            <?php } } else { ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Die Posts entsprechen nicht den Kriterien.' ); ?></p>
            <?php }  ?>

            <!-- pagination -->
                <?php
    if($the_query->max_num_pages>1){?>
        <p class="paged">
        <?php
          if ($paged > 1) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged -1); //prev link ?>"><</a>
                            <?php }
        for($i=1;$i<=$the_query->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . $i; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>
            <?php
        }
        if($paged < $the_query->max_num_pages){?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged + 1); //next link ?>">></a>
        <?php } ?>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
<!--  end pagination -->    


           <!-- end of the loop -->


           <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


    </main>
```

When I'm looking through the source code I can't find the pagination. What am I doing wrong? Can't find an answer, no code works for me. Would be nice if someone could help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use default WordPress pagination, here is an example:

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
// the loop
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
      the_title();
   endwhile;

// Pagination
echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older', $the_query->max_num_pages );
echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer' );

// clean up after our query
wp_reset_postdata(); 

else:
_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

To display next and previous links automatically, just use these functions:

```
next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link();
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination could help with this.  In custom loops it helps to pass in the $max_pages variable as zero for unlimited pages, so it'd look like:

```
next_posts_link("Older Posts", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pagination to include page links, in the format < 1 2 3 > rather than just next/previous links, you can use the WordPress function [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

So for your example the code would look like this:

```
<?php 
//query
$paged = (isset($_REQUEST['paged']) && $_REQUEST['paged'] > 0 ? $_REQUEST['paged'] : max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//loop
if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        //display your post here
    }  

    //pagination
    if($the_query->max_num_pages > 1){ ?> 
        <div class="paged">
            <?php 
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => $paged,
                'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                'prev_text' => __('« Previous'),
                'next_text' => __('Next »'),
            ) ); 
            ?> 
        </div> 
    <?php }

} else {
    echo '<p>'._e( 'Die Posts entsprechen nicht den Kriterien.' ).'</p>';   
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```